# Problem reading Kudu tables using Spark (Jupyer Notebook with Apache Toree - Scala Kernel )

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-toree

I am trying to read a Kudu table using Apache Spark within a Jupyter Notebook running with an Apache Toree - Scala Kernel.

Spark version : 2.2.0
Scala version : 2.11
Apache Toree version : 0.3

This is the code I am using to read the Kudu table

```
val kuduMasterAddresses = KUDU_MASTER_ADDRESSES_HERE
val kuduMasters: String = Seq(kuduMasterAddresses).mkString(",")

val kuduContext = new KuduContext(kuduMasters, spark.sparkContext)

val table = TABLE_NAME_HERE

def readKudu(table: String) = {
    val tableKuduOptions: Map[String, String] = Map(
    "kudu.table"  -> table,
    "kudu.master" -> kuduMasters
    )
    spark.sqlContext.read.options(tableKuduOptions).kudu
}

val kuduTableDF = readKudu(table)
```

Using *kuduContext.tableExists(table)* returns *true*.
Using *kuduTableDF.columns* gives an array of String with the right column names.

The problem occurs when I try to apply an action like count, show etc ... the current exception is thrown:

> Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException Message: Job aborted due to
> stage failure: Exception while getting task result:
> java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext$TimestampAccumulator
> StackTrace:   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1567)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1555)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1554)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1554)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1782)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1737)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1726)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:619)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2031)   at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2052)   at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2071)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2865)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2154)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2154)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2846)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2845)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2154)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2367)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:641)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:600)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:609)

I have already used the *AddDeps* magic in the Apache Toree notebook as follows:

```
%AddDeps org.apache.kudu kudu-spark2_2.11 1.6.0 --transitive --trace
%AddDeps org.apache.kudu kudu-client 1.6.0 --transitive --trace
```

I have no problems doing the following import :

```
import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
```